# Syntax for bracket-notation-property-accessors to conditionally access the entire object rather than a given property

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following:

```
const myFunction = ({ returnProp = null }) => ({
    propA: 'val1',
    propB: 'val2',
    propC: 'val3'
})[returnProp || {}]
//               ^^
//               not sure what to put here
```

If `returnProp` is null, how can I return the whole object?

If I specify `returnProp`, I would like it returned:

```
const propA = myFunction({ returnProp: 'propA' }) // 'val1'
```

If I do not specify it, I'd like the whole object:

```
const obj = myFunction({})
/*
    {
        propA: 'val1',
        propB: 'val2',
        propC: 'val3'
    }
*/
```

Comment: Are you happy to change the way you're arranging the code? If not, then I suppose the question is, is there a syntax fir bracket-notation-property-accessors to access the entrie object rather than a given property?

Comment: That's probably how I should rephrase the title of this question, yes

Comment: What's the problem in saving the object in a variable and then decide if you want to return a specific property or the whole object?

Comment: That was going to be my question @Yousaf. Beaten by seconds. Mike, it just sounds like you're making your code much more complicated that it needs to be.

Comment: @Yousaf Nothing wrong, it's just a general question about javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```js
const myFunction = ({ returnProp = null }) => {
  const obj = {
    propA: "val1",
    propB: "val2",
    propC: "val3",
  };
  return obj[returnProp] ?? obj;
};

console.log(myFunction({ returnProp: "propA" }));
console.log(myFunction({ returnProp: null }));
console.log(myFunction({ returnProp: undefined }));
console.log(myFunction({}));
```

Comment: I'd prefer `return returnProp ? obj[returnProp] : obj` to express more directly what it's supposed to do…

Answer (score 2):

Could maybe use a getter invoked with an empty string:

```js
const myFunction = ({ returnProp = '' }) => ({
    propA: 'val1',
    propB: 'val2',
    propC: 'val3',
    get ['']() {delete this['']; return this}
})[returnProp]


console.log(myFunction({ returnProp: "propA" }));
console.log(myFunction({}));
```